# An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 1.0: Unable to upload new release wwjw_links-2.1.3.tgz

Tags: magento

An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect 1.0.

```
Unable to upload new release wwjw_links-2.1.2.tgz

Package has been successfully uploaded to Magento Connect channel ver.2.0
```

Can anyone help me with solution?